# Search and pagination sql query php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pagination, listjs

Hello I am newbie in php and learning about how to use search and pagination using [List.Js](http://listjs.com)and php
I am having problem to get list.js working to search and filter query result in php. I am already following the example in documentation but still no luck.
Here my code:

```
<div class="box-body">

<div id="listperson" align="center">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="fuzzy-search"/>
<table class="col-md-12">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1 sort"></th>
            <th class="col-md-3 sort" data-sort="nama">Name</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 sort" data-sort="role">Role</th>
            <th class="col-md-3 sort">Email</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2 sort">No.Hp</th>
            <th class="col-sm-3 sort" data-sort="alamat">Alamat</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1 sort">Edit</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1 sort">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        $peoplequery=mysqli_query($CONN,"SELECT * FROM people");
        while($people=mysqli_fetch_array($peoplequery)){
        ?>
    <tbody class="list">            
        <tr align="left">
            <td class="img">
            <img src="../img/man-128.png" class="direct-chat-img" width="10px" height="10px">
            </td>
            <td class="name"><a href="personview.php?PersonID=<?= $people['idpeople'] ?>"><?php echo $people['namadepan'] . ' ' .$people['namabelakang']; ?></a></td>
            <td class="role"><?php echo $people['role']; ?></td>
            <td class="email"><?php echo $people['email']; ?></td>
            <td class="nohp"><?php echo $people['nohp']; ?></td>
            <td class="alamat"><?php echo $people['alamat']; ?></td>                   
            <td class="edit" align="center">
            <a href="editperson.php?PersonID=<?= $people['idpeople'] ?>">
            <span class="fa-stack">
            <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            </a>
            </td>
            <td class="delete" align="center">
            <a href="deleteperson.php?PersonID=<?= $people['idpeople'] ?>">
            <span class="fa-stack" style="color:#ff0000; ">
            <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" ></i>
            </span>
            </a>
            </td>             
        </tr>
        <?php
        $idppl = $people['idpeople'];
        }  ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<ul class="pagination"></ul>
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name', 'role', 'email'],
    page: 5,
    plugins: [
    ListPagination({})
]

};
var contactList = new List('listperson', options);
</script>

</div>
```

The pagination is not showing and search not working also. I wonder what i'm missing here
Any help appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your opening `<tbody>` tag is inside your `while` loop, but your closing `</tbody>` tag is outside that loop.

That probably means your table is malformed. That probably confuses `List.js` .

It's always good to use `View Source...` to check whether HTML is correctly generated.

Comment: Thanks the pagination works now. But the search result is return wrong data right now and in view source nothing error showed.

Comment: You're not necessarily looking for errors in View Source. Instead, you're looking for the structure of the table you're passing into the javascript. You're looking to see whether it has the format you expect.